# Python - Generate Strings for Times of Day

Tags: python

I need a way to generate a list of all five minute increments between some arbitrary set of hours.  So, for example, if I wanted 3p and 4p, it would look like:

3:00 PM, 3:10 PM, 3:15 PM, 3:20 PM, etc....

Any thoughts on the quickest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

QuicknDirty

```
for i in range (60):
   if i % 5 == 0:
      print('X:{}PM'.format (i))
```

Or as function ;)

```
def getMinutes (hour, minuteSteps):
    steps = []
    for i in range (60):
       if i % minuteSteps == 0:
           steps.append('{}:{}PM'.format (hour,i))
    return steps
```

Comment: Consider using the format string of `'{}:{:02d} PM'` to zero pad those times where the minute is less than 10.

Comment: How would this handle crossing over from 11a-12p?

Comment: You can eliminate the if statement if you use `for i in range(0, 60, minuteSteps)`

Comment: Also, I really want it to be flexible so in case I needed 5 hours (say from 11a-4p), it could do that.

Comment: You could archive this with wrapping another for loop around it like for hour in range (11, 16): hour = hour % 12. The modulo 12 gives you your am/pm stuff.